# Use TeamCity environment variable in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, teamcity

I have a TeamCity environment variable `env.TIER_SUFFIX` whose value is set as `A`. I want to be able to use this in my script build step where the script content is

```
    #!/bin/bash 
    tierSuffix=%env.TIER_SUFFIX%
    echo "TierSuffix is [${'$'}tierSuffix]"
    export ENV_TIER=%env.DEV_tierSuffix%
```

The build fails because `export ENV_TIER=%env.DEV_tierSuffix%` creates env.DEV_ and the build stops. Is there a way to use this in the export command so that it substitutes the value of `%env.DEV_A%`   to ENV_TIER

Comment: It's not clear what you want.  Are you looking for `export ENV_TIER=env.DEV_"${tierSuffix}"`?  Or are there more TC variables that you want expanded?

Comment: I also have a TC variable `%env.DEV_A%` where the value `A` comes from the `tierSuffix` and when i export `export ENV_TIER=%env.DEV_"${tierSuffix}%"` I want the value of `%env.DEV_A%` to be substituted

Comment: Did you ever figure this out

Answer (score 1):

The way I use TeamCity variables in bash scripts is:

```sh
buildCounter="%build.counter%"
```

where `build.counter` is TeamCity variable.